# How do I get a list of members of a voice channel in discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im trying to get a list of all the members that are connected to a voice channel in discord and get the username of each member.

Comment: The member list of a voicechannel can be accessed like this :
https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### VoiceChannel#members

`members` is the GuildMember objects collection property of everyone inside of a VoiceChannel. We could simply turn this collection into an array, and scroll through the entire array to return the member's username.

#### Final Code:

```
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'channel name');
if (channel.type !== 'voice') return; // returns the command if the channel is not a voice channel
channel.members.array().forEach(member => {
  console.log(member.user.username);
});
```